# How to do a simple PHP Multisort

Tags: php

From the queried database, we got this

```
foreach ($child_posts as $child_post) {
 $child_id = $child_post->ID;
 $dayOfWeek = get_post_meta($child_id,'wpcf-day-of-week', true);
 $time = get_post_meta($child_id,'wpcf-time', true);

$class[] = array('day' => $dayOfWeek, 'time' => $time, 'value' => $child_id);
}

{"classes":[
{"day":"7","time":"1500","value":13574},
{"day":"7","time":"1800","value":13573},
{"day":"4","time":"1900","value":11346},
{"day":"6","time":"1100","value":11494},
{"day":"5","time":"1800","value":11362},
{"day":"7","time":"1700","value":13572},
{"day":"6","time":"1600","value":11498},
{"day":"6","time":"1500","value":11496}]}
```

Day = Mon - Sun

Time = Military time

Value = something I need, but do not need sorting

I need to sort first by day, then by time. And get back the database in the format like how it was

```
{"classes":[
{"day":"4","time":"1900","value":11346},
{"day":"5","time":"1800","value":11362},
{"day":"6","time":"1100","value":11494},
{"day":"6","time":"1500","value":11496},
{"day":"6","time":"1600","value":11498},
{"day":"7","time":"1500","value":13574},
{"day":"7","time":"1700","value":13572},
{"day":"7","time":"1800","value":13573}]}
```

I tried using the method in the php manual but I still can't really get it.

This is what I did

```
foreach ($class as $key => $row) {
    $day[$key]  = $row['day'];
    $time[$key] = $row['time'];
    $value[$key] = $row['value'];

}

$class[] = array_multisort($day, SORT_DESC, $time, SORT_ASC, $class);
```

I'm know what I should expect, but I don't know how to go around getting it. Hopefully someone can help out here :)

My orignial script:

```
 $childargs = array(
 'post_type' => 'class',
 'numberposts' => -1,
 'meta_query' => array(array('key' => '_wpcf_belongs_instructor_id', 'value' => $instructor_post_id))
 );
 $child_posts = get_posts($childargs);

 //$child_posts = types_child_posts(‘class’);
 foreach ($child_posts as $child_post) {
  $child_id = $child_post->ID;
  $dayOfWeek = get_post_meta($child_id,'wpcf-day-of-week', true);
  $time = get_post_meta($child_id,'wpcf-time', true);

 $class[] = array('day' => $dayOfWeek, 'time' => $time, 'value' => $child_id);
 }

 echo json_encode(
   array("classes" => $class)
 )
 ?>
```

Comment: what method did you try, what code did you use, what result did that bring and what did you expect/why did you expect that?

Comment: I wanted to ask exactly these questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$json = '{"classes":[
          {"day":"7","time":"1500","value":13574},
          {"day":"7","time":"1800","value":13573},
          {"day":"4","time":"1900","value":11346},
          {"day":"6","time":"1100","value":11494},
          {"day":"5","time":"1800","value":11362},
         {"day":"7","time":"1700","value":13572},
         {"day":"6","time":"1600","value":11498},
       {"day":"6","time":"1500","value":11496}]}';


$array = json_decode($json,true);

$temp = $array['classes'];

foreach($temp as $key=>$value)
{
  $day[] = $value['day'];
  $time[] = $value['time'];
  }

array_multisort($day,SORT_ASC,$time,SORT_ASC,$temp);

$array['classes'] = $temp;

echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

try changing your code to .I assume that $classes contains the json_decoded content.

```
$temp = $classes['classes'];

foreach ($temp as $key => $row) {
$day[]  = $row['day'];
$time[] = $row['time'];
$value[] = $row['value'];
}

 array_multisort($day, SORT_DESC, $time, SORT_ASC, $temp);
 $classes['classes'] = $temp;

 echo json_encode($classes);
```

Comment: I can see that it works there! But I'm having problems trying to make it work on my side. It's similar with what I'm working from in the php manual but I really can't get the output. Please help me with my original script (i'm going to update after this post) if you can..

Comment: @user2216416 .. what are the contents of $classes in foreach loop ?

Comment: I realised why, I needed to do this: $day = array(); $time = array();

Answer (score 0):

To sort an array of rows returned from MYSql by one column.
The problem here is to sort courses by session (1,2) and period (1,2,3) If the session = 3 it means both so in preparing the table for sorting and printing if session == 3 then insert a row 1, and a row 2. Then do the sort. The table contents are in $coursesr.

```
$ar = array();
if ($order == "session"){
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($coursesr); $i++){          
        $ar[0][] = (($coursesr[$i]['session'])*10)+$coursesr[$i]['period'];
        $ar[1][] = $i;
    }
    $b = array_multisort($ar[0],SORT_ASC,SORT_NUMERIC,$ar[1],SORT_ASC,SORT_NUMERIC);        
}else{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($coursesr); $i++){          
        $ar[0][] = ucwords($coursesr[$i]['lastname']);
        $ar[1][] = $i;
    }
    array_multisort($ar[0],SORT_ASC,SORT_NATURAL,$ar[1],SORT_ASC,SORT_NUMERIC);
}
```

Then to get it out of the $coursesr array you have to compute the index...

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++){
    $r = $coursesr[$ar[1][$i]]; // simplify reference   
    echo "<tr>";.....
```